# How to download data attribute flag

Tags: wget

I want to take only the graphs that my app have available in a page. The code section where the pics are is like bellow.

```html
<section class="aui-page-panel-content">
                            
    <h2>Database Monitoring</h2>
    <p>SOME TEXT HERE</p>

    <p>
        </p><h5>Connection Pool</h5>
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,[a LOT of characters]">
        <h5>Reads / Writes</h5>
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,[a LOT of characters]">
        <p></p>
</section>
```

If I try to take only png files, there are only icons used in the page and not the graphs. I can't download the whole page and filter everything out afterwards, because it takes too much time.

Comment: perhaps this might be of interest: http://superuser.com/questions/263634/decoding-base64-images-and-saving-to-a-file

Comment: @ewcz Hey, yeah I could work with this :), thanks